# Why does this binding to another Ember object not work?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've set up a simple example of an Ember binding I believe should work: http://jsbin.com/aBekITeT/1/edit

Why is the controller's isTrue property not synced with the model's? Not looking for any "it's bad practice to put things on window" kind of stuff (unless that's actually what's breaking it); I'm looking for understanding here.

My read of http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/ convinced me it should work this way. Could someone explain what I might be interpreting wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> unless that's actually what's breaking it

That's what is actually breaking it. Bindings only work on Ember objects. `window` is not an Ember Object. There is also a problem with the path being wrong, here is a diagram:

```
   if isTrueBinding is "appController.isTrue",        This will:
   this won't work
               +--------------+                    +--------------+
               |              |                    |              |
      +-------+|    window    |+-----+             |    window    |
      |        |              |      |             |              |
      |        +--------------+      |             +--------------+
      v                              v                 +
  +---------------+        +--------------+            |
  | appController |        |  mod         |            |
  |---------------|        |--------------|            v
  | isTrue        |        |isTrueBinding |        +--------------+
  |               |        |              |        |  mod         |
  |               |        |              |        |--------------|
  |               |        |              |        |isTrueBinding |
  |               |        |              |        |appController |+---> +---------------+
  |               |        |              |        |              |      | appController |
  |               |        |              |        |              |      |---------------|
  |               |        |              |        |              |      | isTrue        |
  +---------------+        +--------------+        |              |      |               |
                                                   |              |      |               |
                                                   |              |      |               |
                                                   +--------------+      |               |
                                                                         |               |
                                                                         |               |
             i.e. bindings are implicitly pointing to "this",            |               |
             unless they start with a capital letter.                    +---------------+
```

When bindings do start with a capital letter, the refer to a global object, e.g:

```
window.Currency = Em.Object.create({
  "USD": "$"
});

App.MyObject = Em.Object.extend({
  currencyBinding: "Currency.USD"
});
```

However, using bindings to bind to global objects is not considered good style in Ember - best practice is to use dependency injection to access shared objects. If you find yourself needing to use a global binding, this is likely a sign you need to refactor.

Comment: But appController is an ember object? I'm not binding to a property of window

Comment: actually that's not even the only thing that's broken. Bindings are relative to the object you declare them in. So your binding to `appController.isTrue` is pointing to window.mod.appController.isTrue whereas the property you want is at window.appController.isTrue. Even if you could bind through the window object (which you can't) it wouldn't work because the path is wrong

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/ seemed to imply it was a global path

Comment: The guide is confusing  and I have filed a [pull request to update it](https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/1212).

Comment: This is super helpful
Could you elaborate what happens when they do start with a capital?